# A New, Possible Proof of the Infinitude of the Primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-factorization

$$1=1$$

$$2=2$$

$$3=3$$

$4=2\cdot2$ At $4$, the first prime number, $2$, is there as a factor. So I say that at the square of $2$, $2$ comes into play as a prime factor. At this point, $2$ is the only prime factor in play, and therefore, until $3$ comes into play at $9$, there will be a prime at every other integer.

\begin{align}
5 & = 5 \\
6 & = 2\cdot3 \\
7 & = 7 \\
8 & =2^3
\end{align}

$9$ is the square of $3$, where $3$ comes into play at. With 2 and 3 being the only prime factors in play between 9 and 25, there have to be primes in this interval because 2 and 3 can only hit at most three out of four consecutive integers.

When 5 comes into play at 25, 2,3, and 5 are the only prime factors in play until the square of the next prime, 7, which comes into play at 49. Out of six consecutive integers, 2,3, and 5 can hit at most five of them. So the biggest prime gap between 25 and 49 is 6.

Each prime comes into play as a factor at its own square. So each time we arrive at the square of a prime, one more prime factor is in play, however, the gaps between the squares of the primes grow such that there will always be another prime, at least one in each gap.

Is this sufficient to prove the infinitude of the primes? Are the mathematical concepts presented here correct? Can the way this is presented be improved? Can the wording of the mathematical facts be improved?

An explanation is in order. Let us examine some of the gaps between consecutive squares of primes. Quite simply, the number of prime factors in play before the square of the first prime is 0. Therefore each integer between 1 and 4 is prime. After 4 and before 9, 2 cannot hit every point in the gap. The size of this gap equals 2·2, so there are 4 integers of which 2 can at most hit 2. Likewise, between 9 and 25, the number of integers in the gap is equal to 25-9-1, which is 15. In any span of 4 integers, with 2 and 3 being the only prime factors in play, they will miss at least one space. There is a simple proof for this. Once 5 comes into play, the prime factors begin to follow a great pattern.

The great pattern of how the prime factors are arranged is such that they will miss infinitely many spaces. Factoring all composite numbers from 4 to 30 will reveal this great pattern. Note that 30 is the product of the first three primes.

Comment: Question 1: no. Question 2: no. Question 3: yes. Question 4: yes.

Comment: There is a huge gap in logic in the second last paragraph, which amounts to "I don't see why this pattern shouldn't continue" as opposed to any sort of argument.  How confident can you possibly be that the biggest possible prime gap when the first 1 billion primes are in play is smaller than the gap between $p_{1000000000}^2$ and $p_{1000000001}^2$?

Comment: I find this very vague.  Certainly it is widely known that among numbers less than the square of a particular prime $p$, every number is either prime or divisible by some prime number less than $p$.  Where you say "one in each gap", do you mean one in each gap between squares of primes?  Are you trying to say that some prime number must appear in each gap between squares of primes?  If so, how do you prove that?  And when you arrive at the square of the largest prime, if any, then there are no gaps between squares of primes beyond that, so what happens to your argument then?

Comment: In order to have specific suggestions for wording, I'd need at least some good guesses as to what you're trying to say.

Comment: 2 as a factor is at every other integer. 2 hits every other point.

Comment: @ErickWong So a tighter bound on prime gaps is required.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My guess would be that the OP is referring to the maximal spacing between elements of ${\mathbb Z}_{30}^\times$ being equal to $6$.  It's not at all clear, but it would be a reasonable interpretation that can be made precise.

Comment: I am having some initial suspecions about what is intended.  I'll be back, maybe..... ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ErickWong I would multiply the first 1 billion primes and mark the product on the whole number line. Then I would factor each composite number up to the product and examine the arrangement of the 1 billion prime factors. However, it is not practical to do this because of the limits of space and time. Do this with 30, 210, and 2310. I believe that this great pattern continues infinitely.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung That sounds like what I suspected.  In this case, "I believe that this great pattern continues indefinitely" is very, very far from a new proof.  In fact, this pattern would imply the very difficult conjecture that there is always a prime between the squares of two consecutive primes.  AFAIK this is not known, being slightly weaker than Legendre's conjecture and morally (although maybe not provably) much stronger than Baker-Harman-Pintz.

Comment: this looks to be on track, though theres a lot of excess words. the easiest proof in layman terms: consider a world with finite primes, you multiply them all together to get a huge number. then you add 1. this number is divisible by zero of your "finite primes" therefore there are infinite primes

Answer (score 3):

The approach seems to be:

Consider the $n$-th prime $p$. Between $p+1$ and $p^2$ every number is either prime or divisible by one of the first $n$. [TAMO](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/Miracle.html). Therefore, there is at least one prime between $p+1$ and $p^2$, hence there are infinitely many primes.

I don't know what the miraculous step in the middle is supposed to be. I mean, you can't use the Chinese Remainder Theorem since you'd get
$$
\prod_{\text{primes }q\le p} \frac{q-1}{q}
$$
primes but they'd be spread out among the numbers up to
$$
p\#=\prod_{\text{primes }q\le p}q
$$
which is much larger than $p^2$ unless $p$ is tiny.

Let me put it another way. Suppose all you knew about prime divisors was that in a range of $n$ numbers the prime $p$ divides either $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$ or $\lceil n/p\rceil$ of the numbers. So if you look at the range 6 to 30 (25 numbers) you know that 12 or 13 are even, 8 or 9 are divisible by 3, and exactly 5 are divisible by 5. But that's not enough to conclude that there are *any* primes in that interval, since $13+9+5=27\ge25.$ Now it happens that the numbers don't conspire that way and there are primes (like 7) in that interval. But how could you know that a conspiracy doesn't happen with larger intervals? If you look at the interval $(97,\ 97^2]$ you'll find that there are 16777 to 16799 primes 2-97 dividing the 9312 numbers in that range so it's entirely possible (*a priori*) that every number would be covered and there wouldn't be a single prime.

Comment: Yes, indeed it happens that as we go toward infinity that there will be enough prime factors in play to cover every space. Now, not attempting a proof here, but simply stating some facts, the prime factors, although more than enough in quantity to cover every space, will always leave another space open. The primes are where the prime factors are not. Since there are infinitely many primes, the prime factors must be arranged in some orderly way such that there will be infinitely many spaces where none of them will be.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung: That approach doesn't work. You don't have enough control of the congruence classes in the limit.

Comment: @Charles: +1 for TAMO. (I was wondering what that acronym meant.)   :)

Comment: Your link is dead. I guess it was the Sidney Harris cartoon?

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's a guess as to what is meant: among the numbers $1,2,3,4,\ldots,(p_1\cdots p_n)$,
where $p_1<\cdots<p_n$ are the $n$ smallest primes, only $p_1\cdots p_n - (p_1-1)\cdots(p_n-1)$ of them can be divisible by at least one of the primes $p_1,\ldots,p_n$; therefore the others must be divisible by some other primes; hence there are more primes than $p_1,\ldots,p_n$.

But the argument is not clearly expressed here.